# Selecting point with shiny and plotly

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

I have been trying for some time to debug my Shiny gadget but still cannot manage it. Really appreciate any help.

My gadget consists of a scatterplot generated with Plotly. The user can click one of the points, which will allow you to change some parameters associated with that point. To emphasise the fact that the user has selected that point, I wanted to highlight the selected  point.

Alternatively, the user can also select a point from a dropdown menu, which also should highlight the corresponding point.

As an added feature, I want to additionally highlight points that are below a certain threshold on the x axis. This threshold is represented by a dotted line, which you can turn on and off, and move the value of the threshold.

In summary, the points on the plot should all be blue circles, except for the following two cases:

1. if it is clicked, i.e. it is the "active point" (this should create a red border around the point)
2. if it is below the threshold on the x-axis (the point should turn to an orange square)

If it is active AND below the threshold, it should be an orange square with a red border, as you would expect.

My gadget works, kind of. But in some cases not. In the example below, one of the points is already below the threshold, but when I select that point, the red marker appears on another point! Despite the active variable being the correct one.

I also get a weird behaviour that the points turn purple if the threshold is below all of the points. But if I move the threshold to be above one of the points, the colours are corrected.

I have a suspicion that this is something to do with the points being on different traces? Therefore when I try to highlight certain points, perhaps I am not indexing the vector as I am expecting. But I am finding it really difficult to debug inside Shiny and Plotly, and I have no good understanding of the Plotly object, so I don't have much clue as to what is going on.

The code below is a reproducible example. You have to run "dat1" through the "rew8r" function. I have taken out other features of the app to try to focus on the problem. Thanks very much to anyone who might take the time to have a look at this, and give any hints!

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

dat1 <- data.frame(
  Indicator = c("v1","v2","v3"),
  Weight = rep(1,3),
  Correlation = c(0.1, 0.8, 0.6) )

rew8r <- function(dat){

# get indicator names
inames <- dat$Indicator

## Create the shiny UI layout
ui <- fluidPage(
  # the side panel
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("vseldrop", "Select indicator here or by clicking a point on plot.",
                c("<Select>",inames)),
    hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #000000;"),
    fluidRow(
      column(6,numericInput("locorval", "Low correlation threshold:", 0.2, min = -1, max = 1, step = 0.05)),
      column(6,br(),checkboxInput("locorsw", "Enable", value = FALSE)))
    
  ),
  # the main panel (graph, table, etc)
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("corrplot"),
    textOutput("info")
  )
)

## Create the Shiny Server layout
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # this is the plotly click data
  event.data <- reactive({event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "scplot")})
  
  # First, monitor which variable is active
  # Create reactive value for active var
  acvar <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  # update active variable via plot click
  observeEvent(event.data(),{
               acvar(event.data()$key)})
  # update active variable via dropdown
  observeEvent(input$vseldrop,
               acvar(input$vseldrop))
  
  ## Create the plotly plot that compares price vs scoops
  output$corrplot <- renderPlotly({
    
    # colours around markers when selected or not
    lincol <- ifelse(inames %in% acvar(), "red", "blue")
    # size of line around marker (set to 0 if not selected)
    linsize <- ifelse(inames %in% acvar(), 3, 0)

    # symbol when above/below corr threshold
    symbs <- if(input$locorsw==TRUE){c(16,15)}else{c(16,16)}
    # colour when above/below threshold
    pcols <- if(input$locorsw==TRUE){c("blue", "orange")}else{c("blue", "blue")}
    
    # generate main plot
    p <- plot_ly(dat, x = ~Correlation, y = ~Weight, type = "scatter", mode = "markers",
            text = ~Indicator, key = ~Indicator, source = "scplot",
            marker = list(size = 10, line = list(color = lincol, width = linsize)),
            symbol = ~Correlation < input$locorval, symbols = symbs,
            color = ~Correlation < input$locorval, colors = pcols) %>%
      layout(showlegend = FALSE, yaxis = list(
        range = c(0, 1.25),
        autotick = FALSE,
        dtick = 0.25),
        xaxis = list(
          range = c(-0.5, 1),
          autotick = FALSE,
          dtick = 0.2))
    
    # add low correlation line, if activated
    if(input$locorsw==TRUE){
      p <- p %>% add_segments(x = input$locorval, xend = input$locorval, y = 0, yend = 1.25,
                              marker = list(color = 'red', opacity=0),
                              line = list(dash = 'dash')) %>%
        layout(showlegend = FALSE)
    }

    p
    
  })
  
  # Text info
  output$info <- renderText({
    paste(acvar(), class(acvar()))
  })
  
  # update dropdown menu
  observeEvent(acvar(),{
    updateSelectInput(session, "vseldrop", selected = acvar())
  })
  
}

runGadget(ui, server, viewer = browserViewer())

}
```

Comment: I've reproduced this and it looks pretty weird - I'm starting to think it's a bug in the plotly package. If you remove `symbol = ~Correlation < input$locorval, symbols = symbs, color = ~Correlation < input$locorval, colors = pcols` then it works OK. Something to do with the way it splits up the data to handle those inequalities.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Yeah it's strange. The plotly click data also sometimes randomly changes to a list rather than a character string. Anyway I appreciate your effort.